# How to implement SSO on Mac and IPAD

Tags: macos, ipad, authentication, kerberos

We have a web application that uses SSO to authenticate users. On Windows everything works well. Now the question is how to make it work on OSX and IPAD? Is this possible in principle. I don't have much experience with OSX. Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tutorial on how to setup Kerberos for OS X here: http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/kerberos-mac-os-x. After that Safari should automatically work with the SSO, Firefox & Chrome may need further settings configured.

For iOS devices I'm unsure, it appears that to do it it requires either the device is in an Enterprise group, or that you build it with the iOS Configurator application but it's not entirely clear on how it should be done.